# getting a list of divs within a parent (querySelectorAll)

Tags: javascript

I have a simple bar chart, as shown below, - each bar is a simple div contained within a parent div. I'd like to iterate through the parent div and pull the value and `data-cat` attribute for further processing.

```
<div class="chart">
  <!-- other stuff here.... -->
  <div class="graph">
    <div id="b-2_1" class="bar" data-cat="1" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_2" class="bar" data-cat="3" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_3" class="bar" data-cat="6" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_4" class="bar" data-cat="9" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I've tried variations of querySelectorAll without success - I'm messing up the syntax somehow.

```
 //finds chart within a parent div not shown above
 var chart = $('#comment-' + index).find('.chart'); 

//var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll('.graph');
var everyChild = chart.querySelectorAll('.graph');
for (var i = 0; i<everyChild.length; i++) {
    console.log(everyChild[i]);
}
```

`document.querySelectorAll('.graph');` returns a result, but as there's more than one graph on the page, it returns multiple results. How can I use `chart` as a point of reference o I can get the data on an individual graph? At the moment it's returning the error `chart.querySelectorAll('.graph') is not a function`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is jquery allowed ??

Comment: Why not use the `id` as selector?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0].children`
note that the `[0]` can be an var which increments for every chart there is.

Comment: That's because `chart` is a jQuery context and not a native DOM element hence doesn't have the `querySelectorAll` method. If you're already using jQuery, you can simply try `$('#comment-' + index).find('.chart .bar').each(function() { var cat = $(this).data('cat'); ... })`

Comment: @A.T. - yes, query is allowed. 

@elementzero23 - there are multiple graphs, and getting the id involves a little more work. which is not a problem, and is what I will do if the above is a non-runner. At the moment it just suits my purposes more to get the get the contents of `<div class="graph">` using <div id="comment-1" class="chart"> as a start point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is great, should be use if possible, here is how you can traverse in given DOM.

```js
var charts = $('.chart > .graph');
charts.each(function(i,graph){
  console.log("Graph: "+ i)
    $(graph).find('.bar').each(function(j,bar){
      console.log("data-cat: "+ bar.getAttribute('data-cat'))
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart">
  <!-- other stuff here.... -->
  <div class="graph">
    <div id="b-1_1" class="bar" data-cat="2" style="width: 80%;">2</div>
    <div id="b-1_2" class="bar" data-cat="4" style="width: 80%;">2</div>
    <div id="b-1_3" class="bar" data-cat="6" style="width: 80%;">2</div>
    <div id="b-1_4" class="bar" data-cat="8" style="width: 80%;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="graph">
    <div id="b-2_1" class="bar" data-cat="1" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_2" class="bar" data-cat="3" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_3" class="bar" data-cat="6" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_4" class="bar" data-cat="9" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery has a built-in function [to access `data-` attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: @elementzero23 but that's not compatible with <IE9

Answer (score 0):

You can change the querySelector itself to something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.chart .graph');
```

Furthermore you should take a look at the documentation of `querySelectorAll()` it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and you can perform a loop through a NodeList by calling `.forEach()` on the NodeList `everyChild`

Even though this should be a solution I would recommend using something like jQuery.

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting IDs to your parent divs:

```
<div class="graph" id="graph1">
    <div id="b-2_1" class="bar" data-cat="1" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_2" class="bar" data-cat="3" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_3" class="bar" data-cat="6" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
    <div id="b-2_4" class="bar" data-cat="9" style="width: 80%;">4</div>
</div>
```

And then do

```
$("#graph1").children().each(function () {
    var cat = $(this).data("cat");
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```